# Defining piecewise constant functions in a GUI

Tags: gui-design, math

I was posting my question on StackOverflow
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44927697/defining-piecewise-constant-functions-in-a-gui?noredirect=1#comment76852785_44927697)
 a couple of days ago, but now a commentator referred me to this forum.

Currently, I am working on a program with a GUI. My application computes several things, given a function, which the user can enter. Right now, the users are only able to enter constant functions into my program. I'd like to be able to allow also piecewise-constant functions.

What would be a good interface for a user to enter piecewise functions? The user should be able to enter a finite number of intervals on which the function has a certain constant value. How would this be done nicely?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

1. Right now, users can enter constant functions via a simple Textline,
   where they enter a non-negative real number.
2. A definition and examples of piecewise constant functions can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function

Comment: Welcome! Would you be able add some examples of piecewise functions (or some examples of the different function "*pieces*")? Showing us how you're currently allowing the users to enter constant functions would also be helpful.

Comment: No expert here, but a quick Google tells me piecewise can have sub-functions, is there a limit? Would you impose a limit?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious way would be a simple two-column table of transition values and the values of the function between those transitions; something like:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyzQrg.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

(with appropriate controls to add/remove rows; possibly a command to split an existing range).

More complicated options could include a range of "pre-defined" functions, e.g. step-function (f(x)=0 if x<0, =1 otherwise), rectangular function (f(x)=1 over a given range, =0 otherwise) etc.